# _cgo_export.c:3:10: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found while running go test in VS Code after upgrading to mac OS Ventura

Tags: macos, go

Here is the corrected syntax for the given text:

Go Version: 1.9
MacOS: Ventura
goFileContent:

```
   package main

   import (
   “fmt”
   )

   func main() {
   fmt.Println(“HelloWord”)
    }
```

> Error occurred: _cgo_export.c:3:10: fatal error: ‘stdlib.h’ file not found.

When I try to fix this issue using ‘sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include /usr/include’, I get a new error: ln: /usr/include: Read-only file system.

When I try to fix the above issue using ‘sudo mount -uw /’, I get another error: mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied.

What should I do now? Thank you.

I hope to be able to run my code successfully. Can you please guide me on what I should do? Thank you.

Comment: Go 1.9 is ancient. It came out in 2017. Go 1.20 is the current version. You should definitely upgrade your Go version.

Comment: [Searching the 'net for the exact error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=_cgo_export.c%3A3%3A10%3A+fatal+error%3A+%E2%80%98stdlib.h%E2%80%99+file+not+found.) lists lots of approaches to fix the problem. None of them relates to Go, though (i.e., an attempt to compile a "hello world" C programs fails in the same way), so I'm afraid you'd need to try all these things until some of them works. I'd start with running `go build -x` (notice `-x`) to see which exact commands get executed for building/linking and maybe first try to make compiling simple C code work.

Comment: …and yes, while _probably_ not the cause of the problem, 1.9 is not supported _for long,_ so if you'll end up finding that the roadblock you've hit actually relates to Go, no one will work on your problem, unfortunately as 1.9 is way past the two supported releases, which are now 1.19 and 1.20.